# change font color in evernote mac with automator

Tags: macos, fonts, colors, automator, evernote

Can any one give some hints for a script that on a keystroke changes the font color in Evernote? I need to let's say, change the color beforehand. Like am writing and press a hotkey and then on, text is red... another keystroke black again. If I use the color picker I have to change colors after I wrote them.

Thanks
dan

Comment: This might suit somewhere like SuperUser (http://superuser.com/) more than Stack Overflow. See this page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for types of questions that should be asked on Stack Overflow.